# Pictures on Multiple Forms crash VB 2019 projects

Tags: vb.net

Using Visual Studio 2019, VB Windows Forms App(.Net Framework) template, my students are building projects using multiple forms, pictures (as background images and in picture boxes) and timers. When they have two or more pictures, the programs crash irretrievably.

The error message is:

> Error while trying run project: (path to project location) Access is
> denied.

Even if they remove the pictures, the error remains and the program no longer works. I never experienced this problem when we were using VB2015.
My student assistant tried to replicate the problem on (Vis Studio 2019) his home computer and couldn't.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question. You can then come back and [edit] your question with the necessary details.  As is, the question cannot be answered by any means other than guess-work, which is not ideal.  For starters, you can add a [mcve] of the issue you are describing

Comment: Most likely whoever installed Visual Studio for 15 had to setup special permissions so that students could run the generated .EXE in the \bin folder, and this wasn't done for the new install of VS19. Most school environments have account permissions in play, as well as additional security programs in play preventing student accounts from doing devious things, and VS19 is being perceived as "devious" because it's generating an EXE and trying to run it.

Comment: "My student assistant tried to replicate the problem on (Vis Studio 2019) his home computer and couldn't." Most computers in a home environment are running under an Admin account, thus no access denied errors.

Comment: "Access is denied" points more too a environmental/directory permissions error too me.  You might be better off going to you IT department for a resolution on this

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an antivirus you may add an Exception to the project path.

You may also try to run VB2019 as Administrator to see if that was the problem, click on the VS2019 icon using the right button of the mouse and then click on Execute as Administrator.